# Check Entry widget for blanks

Tags: tkinter

I have a similar line for all the Entry widgets in the window. If all have an entry, a button is drawn, if any one is empty the button is not drawn or removed. I want the user to input a specific number instead of accepting a default value.

```
any_entry = ttk.Entry(...)
any_entry.bind('<Key>', is_empty)
```

This is the handler:

```
def is_empty(event):
    for child in window.winfo_children():
        if child.winfo_class() == 'TEntry':
            if child.get() == '':
                calc_btn.grid_remove()
                return
    calc_btn.grid()
```

The problem I encounter is that the handler is called at any key press but the value stored in the widget textvariable doesn't update until the next key press or widget losing focus. If I put a number in each of the Entry widgets the calc_button is displayed. If I focus on any Entry and delete the entry the button does not get removed until another key press or move focus. That allows the user to click the calc_button exposing a possiblity of an exception or error down the road as one Entry could yield a null value. Any suggestions on how to better handle this?

Answer (score 1):

This is programmed using class, hope you know how it works. If not I recommend learning it.

```
from tkinter import *



class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entry1 = Entry(self)
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry2 = Entry(self)
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.entry1.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.check, add = "+")
        self.entry2.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.check, add = "+")
        self.button = Button()
    def check(self, event):
        if not self.entry1.get() == "" and not self.entry2.get() == "":
            self.button.pack()      
        else:
            self.button.pack_forget()
root = App()
root.mainloop()
```

I bind "< KeyRelease >" instead of "< KeyPress > " because when both entries have only one character, it gets checked only on the next KeyPress event, because it seems the manual binds fire first, then the default(which is most likely a class bind). I've read a post here on SO where Mr.Oakley (highly skilled tkinter guy) explained the order of firing of bindings. And entries have most likely KeyPress binded to them, logically you press first, release later :)

Comment: Perfect! I don't understand and can't find any info on the third argument (add = '+'). Can you explain or direct me to a source that explains? P.S. my sample didn't reflect but I am using class structure.

Comment: Adds an event binding to this widget. Usually, the new binding replaces any existing binding for the same event sequence. By passing in “+” as the third argument, the new callback is added to the existing binding. Source: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm I added it there to make sure I don't interfiere with the existing default binding.